# Sitecore no layout found

Tags: sitecore

I'm working on a Sitecore site that's part of a multi-site installation that uses a shared codebase (dlls, etc...) and my own code. Unfortunately I don't know much about the shared code as I didn't write any of it.

A recent build has caused my site to stop working. Whenever I try to browse to a page directly I get an error that the layout cannot be found ({00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}). However, if I try to preview the same page from Content Editor, it will display. I've tried undoing pending changes and rolling back code but it's not working. Any ideas/help would be appreciated.

Comment: Look through all custom pipeline processors (which you can find in config patch files) and see if there's any layout substitution logic going on there.

Comment: I understand that Sitecore makes providing a [mcve] quite difficult, but it's absolutely necessary to reproduce the issue before any help can be given toward solving it. I would hazard a guess that you haven't assigned a layout to the specific item you're viewing, but it's purely speculative until you've provided some way to identify the issue.

Comment: There is layout assigned to the page, I've verified. I don't think Preview would work if there wasn't.

Comment: Are you sure everything is published (items, layouts, ..)? Is there anything in the logs?

Comment: Check your site configuration and resolving. It might be that the wrong site is resolved from the domain you use.

Comment: I've gotten a couple of dings for asking this question "incorrectly." Real question: What sort of example could I have provided in this case to make the question more appropriate? As noted, Sitecore isn't exactly helpful in this regard, especially given that the site is behind a firewall with no access to the outside world.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After much searching and getting help from the folks who wrote the foundation it was discovered that there was a missing configuration that was causing the wrong site definition file to be referenced.

Answer (score 2):

I often see this issue when Templates are missing from the Web database.

Preview generally works from the Master database, so it isn't affected by unpublished content in the Web database.

Try doing a full republish of the User Defined templates folder:

`/sitecore/templates/User Defined`